# Printing C Array to a terminal

Tags: c, unix

I need to read in a file from C, store it in an array and print its contents. For some reason I keep seeing octal in my output near the end. I am dynamically creating the array after counting how many lines and characters are in it after opening the file.

output:

```
Abies 
abies 
abietate 
abietene 
abietic 
abietin
\320ѿ_\377Abietineae --> umlaut? where did he come from?
y\300_\377abietineous
```

code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

char c = '\0';
FILE * file;
int i = 0, j = 0, max_line = 0, max_char_per_line = 0;

/* get array limits */
file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
        max_line++; j++;
        if (j > max_char_per_line){
            max_char_per_line = j;
        }
        j = 0;
        continue;
    }
    j++;
}

rewind(file);
/* declare array dynamically based on max line and max char */
char word[max_line][max_char_per_line];

/*read in file*/
j = 0; c = '\0';

while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
    if (c == '\n'){
        word[i][j] = '\0';
        i++; j=0;
        continue;
    }

    word[i][j] = c;
    j++;
}
word[i][j] = '\0';

fclose(file);
for (i = 0; i < max_line; i++){
    printf("%s\n", word[i]);
}



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code updated to account for spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change read routine:

```
   if (c == '\n'){
        word[i][j] = 0x0;
        i++; j=0;
        continue;
    }
```

and add the "\n" back in the printf routine.

```
for (i = 0; i < max_line; i++){
    printf("%s\n", word[i]);
}
```

C strings are zero-terminated, not "\n"-terminated, so when you printf()ed them, `printf()` did not know where to stop printing.

Comment: pardon my noobery, but why 0x0 (hex) and not just 0? at word[i][j] = 0x0;

Comment: Oh, that's just a habit. Not even one of my worst :-) -- I use it to recognize characters at a glance. But it is completely equivalent to `=0`. Actually I would have liked to write `if ('\n' == c)`, that's what I usually do.

Comment: Ahh ('\n' == c) crazy :) Thanks a lot, slowly but surely C is sinking in.

Comment: I recommend "Writing Solid Code" by Steve Maguire. Lots of interesting practices, tricks and habits to take.

Comment: I'll add it to the list. It's in the queue behind C-Programming with Dennis Ritchie and Cormen's Algorithms.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't terminating your strings. You need to add the null-terminator: `\0`, after the last character for each line.

In your first loop, you determine enough space for the longest line, including a newline character.

- If you want to *keep* the newlines in your input array, just add 1 to `max_char_per_line`, and add the null-terminator after the newline character when you finish each line in your second loop.
- If you *don't* need the newline in your input array, instead simply use that space for the null-terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it explains exactly the phenomenon you observe, but it may. You do not seem to take into account the terminating zero byte when calculating array boundaries. Just `++` the max_char_per_line after doing the calculations. And don't forget to add this zero byte if the array isn't guaranteed to be zero-initialized.

*edit*: do you see these lines *after* the output or in one these lines of output?